# Reopen controller of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rubygems, metaprogramming

I use [inboxes](https://github.com/evrone/inboxes) gem, and I need to add devise method(`:authenticate_user!`) to base_controller of `inboxes` gem. Sorry for my English

Comment: Like all ruby methods, reopen it and add what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Inboxes gem, but if you're not able to specify your own Inboxes controller (for instance, through routing), you could consider adding this before_filter to your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user! if self.controller_path == 'inboxes/base'
```

If you can specify your own base controller, you'll be able to extend the Inboxes::BaseController like so:

```
class MyInboxesController < Inboxes::BaseController
  # ...
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you see the Inboxes::BaseController controller, it is inherited from application controller so you can add method to application controller and then method can be used from Inboxes::BaseController.

but if you want to add method inside Inboxes::BaseController then write a monkey patch file for it and place the file inside config/initializer folder

like:

```
class Inboxes::BaseController
  #
  # Add method here  
  # 
end
```

Comment: I cant add this method to ApplicationController because I dont need this.
In second case this not work because it does not know method `before_filter`